# For which status codes does the promise resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to clarify for which http status codes the promise from $http is resolved and for which it is rejected. As I understand it it resolves only in the case of 200, and the rest are rejected.

Is that right? Or are there other cases?

Comment: Have you checked the source?

Comment: you mean the angularjs source code ? or what ?

Comment: [Of course](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js)

Comment: I've looked at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L3
but I didnt found the answer to my question

Comment: Don't look at the promises implementation, but the part that uses them and actually creates `XMLHttpRequest`s. Hint: I've already linked it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit :

For AngularJS

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called.

Source : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js

Comment: thanks for describing, but my question was only about in cases when promise resolving :)

Comment: The question was "what status codes does $http resolve/reject?", not "how can I control which status codes resolve and which reject?"

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi pointed out in the comments to your question, the answer lies in the source code. There is a private function in [$http](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js) called isSuccess, which looks like this:

```
function isSuccess(status) {
  return 200 <= status && status < 300;
}
```

It's used in a couple of places in that file, but the important one for our purposes is this:

```
(isSuccess(status) ? deferred.resolve : deferred.reject)({ //...
```

So there's your answer! Any status code in the 2** (two-hundred-and-something) range is a success and will resolve the promise that $http wraps around the XHR, anything else is a failure and will reject it.

It's also now explained in the [docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).