# angular phonegap - my factory not delivering data

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am trying to create a Phonegap App. I use Angular as frontend.
I have a factory that gets data from an external ressource. In .config i added the access origin * attribute.

When I debug using http://debug.build.phonegap.com it seem to returning the data. The call to the API is returning 584 bytes.

So there seems to be an issue regaring the data from the factory to the frontend.

My Factory

```
    .factory('ActivityService', ['$http', '$location', 'CookieService', function ($http, $location, CookieService) {
    return {

        getActivitiesService: function (data) {

            $http.post('http://www.example.com/api/v1/Activity.php',
                {
                    MethodName: "getActivitiesService",
                    SessionToken: CookieService.getCookie("ua_session_token")
                })
                .success(data)

        },
        postActivityService: function (activity) {
            $http.post('http://www.example.com/api/v1/Activity.php',
                {
                    MethodName: "postActivityService",
                    SessionToken: CookieService.getCookie("ua_session_token"),
                    ActivityName: activity.activityName,
                    ActivityDescription: activity.activityDescription
                }).success(function () {
                    $location.path("/home");
                });

        }
    }
}])
```

My controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'ActivityService', function($scope, ActivityService) {
    //GET activities from server / DB

ActivityService.getActivitiesService(function (data) {
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data))
    {
        $scope.emptyJsonArray = "No activities.";
    }
    else
    {

        $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.activities = data; });
    }

    })
}])
```

In my app.js i do this:

```
//Manually bootstrapping Angular, after cordova.
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['attenttoApp']);
    });
};
```

Update:
Thanks both of you. I checked the content of the returned data, and it was an error that was returned. 
Fixed it and now i works...

Comment: how can you be sure that 584 bytes is the correct data? have u checked the contents of the data? It can be an error message returned from the server. 584 bytes is not much.

Comment: True, i will look into that

Answer (score 0):

in the doc, they use return in factory

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

so try it like this

```
getActivitiesService: function (data) {

        var toreturn = $http.post('http://www.example.com/api/v1/Activity.php',
            {
                MethodName: "getActivitiesService",
                SessionToken: CookieService.getCookie("ua_session_token")
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            })
            return toreturn;
    },
```

and i think you should see in direction of promises, i wrote an answer about this, look at it
[For which status codes promise resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775724/for-which-status-codes-promise-resolving/24776084#24776084)